# Initialize more than one html element using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to lead my html element to fire my customized JS file's method.

Third textarea appears nicely.

First and second textareas does not effect any of the settings i am trying to change in myJSFile.js file.

**Here's my problem : js file loads the last textarea nicely, but cannot initialize previous ones properly using my js methods.**

I'm doing something wrong with my JS file, and i'd appreciate if you help me.

P.S. : Initalizing some plugin and working on CKEditor.

**Here's my HTML file :**

```
<textarea id="myTextAreaID" name="myTextArea"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/myJSFile.js"onload="setTextAreaValues('myTextAreaID')"></script>

<textarea id="myTextAreaID2" name="myTextArea2"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/myJSFile.js"onload="setTextAreaValues('myTextAreaID2')"></script>

<textarea id="myTextAreaID3" name="myTextArea3"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/myJSFile.js"onload="setTextAreaValues('myTextAreaID3')"></script>
```

Here's **myJSFile.js** file

```
var textAreaID;

$(function(){
   var myTextArea = $('#'+textAreaID);
   //something is being loaded here, and it is loaded fine.
});

function setTextAreaParameters(param){
    textAreaID = param;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bit confused what is going on wit this - why is there a script tag declaration with the same source 3 times..

Comment: @gratz because i don't want to initialize my CKEditor plugin in my HTML for its every instance. I am trying to generate these CKEditor textareas more functionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not very good idea to do it like this, however it's interesting to understand why it happens. In  your code below you are defining global variable `textAreaID`:

```
var textAreaID;

$(function() {
    var myTextArea = $('#' + textAreaID);
    //something is being loaded here, and it is loaded fine.
});

function setTextAreaParameters(param) {
    textAreaID = param;
}
```

This script is injected three times into document. After the last `script` tag the value of `textAreaID` variable will be `myTextAreaID3`, because it's global and the last `setTextAreaParameters` invocation will override previous. Remember that scripts are loaded synchronously in your case (no async or deferred attribute), it means that `onload` callbacks don't wait and immediately set `textAreaID` to new values.

However `DOMContentLoaded` event has not yet fired. This is the event you are subscribing with this code:

```
$(function() {
    // DOMContentLoaded
});
```

When it eventually does - only the third textarea will be processed - the one with id `myTextAreaID3`.

Better approach would be to have only one script tag and set textareas the same className attribute:

```
<textarea id="myTextAreaID2" name="myTextArea2" class="editor"></textarea>
```

Then in the script probably have some sort of map with configuration parameters for each individual textarea.

Comment: thank you for explanation. I really don't know how to map my configuration with adding a class attribute into my html element, but i will look up for that.

Answer (score 2):

You are including the same script three times, but the browser is probably smart enough to only load it once (no reason to load the same script on the same page more than once).

What you need to do is to include the script only once, say before the end of the body tag

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/myJSFile.js"></script>
</body>
```

and then in the JS file, wait for the document to load, and handle all text areas accordingly:

```
$(function() {
 $('textarea').each(function(i, j) {
 console.log('do something for the ' + i + 'th text area');
});
})
```